# Which Letter takes up the most EM (globally)?

Tags: styling, placeholder

I was reading up on changing placeholder text when I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949453/3436942).

I went back and learnt about placeholders, anyway. And one SO answer said something along the lines of:

> Be careful when designing your placeholder text, since anything outside of the control will be cut off.

Putting these two answer together, it made me think (yes, I know, bad thing to do!) -

## **What is the longest letter in EM in Global (language) terms?**

*(since we are meant to size letters in EM and all).*

The longest in the ***English*** Alphabet is 'W' apparently (from linked Question) - so in terms of global languages, what is?

---

---

If I had a control such like:

```
+------------------------+
|123456789101112131415161|
+------------------------+
```

where the placeholder was 24 numbers long. How can i ensure they all fit?

Since numbers seem to be the same EM width:

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
55555
66666
77777
88888
99999
```

How can I ensure that 24 characters, no matter what length/EM width will fit?

I could just go:

```
+------------------------+
|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW|
+------------------------+
```

But what if there is a wider letter used from another language? How can I ensure that the placeholder text can be read? (without resizing the input itself dynamically)? I literally want the minimum width it would have to be to display 24 characters, no more - no matter what language is placed in the field.

---

---

Here's an example of an even longer 'letter' than English's **W**:

> WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
> ŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒŒ
> ÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆ

**EDIT**

I know *how* i would test (as above) but not 'contenders' as to which is the widest character in the world?

Comment: "longest" refers to the font and glyph in use. You can select a glyph for the letter "w" such that it is no wider than the letter "m".

Comment: I'm talking more typical, modern fonts. *In modern typefaces, the character M is usually somewhat less than one em wide* ~[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)#Incorrect_and_alternative_definitions). For example MVC's standard Font Is **Segoe UI**, and winforms is **Microsoft Sans Serif**

Comment: Again, what fonts and glyphs are you working with? There are tens of thousands of glyphs. You need to do some research.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I'm using the default for an mvc web app in visual studio? I'm not quite sure what/where the information you are looking for is exactly?

Answer (score 0):

1. determine your font (eg. Arial)
2. determine your font-size (eg. 10px)
3. determine your font-weight (eg. bold)
4. determine your character-set (eg. UTF-8)
5. print a couple of same characters (eg. 24) per row for each character of the character set
6. devide and conquer
   -> remove rows that are obviously shorter than others and refresh the page
   -> repeat removal as long as there are more than one rows on the page (for equally long rows just pick any one)

Comment: basically the 'print' in step 5 converts into "write to html page" (eg. with the help of javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Print each character enclosed by a span and then search for the calculated width for that character (either in your browser's devtools or you can automate this with a simple Javascript script that will check the largest of your characters).

Comment: I will add a script to test that.