# Define a width for each words and compose a title automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I’m searching for a way of automatically 
compose a sentence using javascript.
Here is an example using this sentence : 
**«here is an amazing sentence well composed»**
[image]
Then I’d like the block size to change dependind 
on the word width
[image: Different sizes]
So that finally, it could look like this :[image: Final result]
So far, I only found how to cut the sentences in words.
How could I define a width for each «words / text block»
depending on their width ?

```js
function wordsinblocks() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var res = str.split(" ");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res; 
}
```

```css
 body{
    font-family:"helvetica";
    font-size: 40px;
    }
p {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<button onclick="wordsinblocks();">Design the sentence</button>
<p id="demo">Here is an amazing sentence well composed</p>
```

Comment: you want to have divs for each words with width depends upon their word width?

Comment: Which functionality would you like? Word width and word length are different. Word width would depend very much on the font.

Comment: Why in your final result the 4 character words "here" or "well" takes up the same space with 8 character words like "composed" or "sentence". What exactly is the logic to arrange the word's spacing?

Comment: @Redu I think he wants the word to match a certain grid, as in, make the word contained in the closest size (10%, 30% or 50%) but I'm still not sure where these percentages come from

Comment: @Redu : it's an esthetical effect, not really logical. I'm searching for the grid system to appear in the text...

Comment: @Aziz : the % : 100% is the full page width.

Comment: Not exactly this one but i had done a previous work on a similar case to arrange the font size dynamically to fit a sentence in a div with fixed width. The sentence gets longer font gets smaller or vice versa. Have a look at it for an idea. http://codepen.io/omerillo/pen/bpGqOQ

Comment: I'm confused, you said in your comment that you want word length, but then in your question you want word width. Which do you want? Word length is the number of characters, and word width is the number of pixels.

Comment: @4castle : my mistake, I tought it was the same. Seems to work with the lenght : see beerwin answer. But now I hesitate because, id like it to be responsive.. and maybe it's better in pixel, what do you think ?

Comment: Pixels would probably be safer, because wide characters like `m`, `w` or capital letters might throw it off. It's a little more work to accomplish though. It's only necessary if you find text that breaks it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation that finds the relevant grid size to apply. (*and reruns the fitting code when resizing the browser so that it will work responsively*)

```js
function wordsinblocks(self) {
    var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
        initialText = demo.textContent,
        wordTags = initialText.split(" ").map(function(word){
          return '<span class="word">' + word + '</span>';
        });
  
    demo.innerHTML = wordTags.join('');
    self.disabled = true;
    fitWords();
    window.addEventListener('resize', fitWords);
}

function fitWords(){
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
      width = demo.offsetWidth,
      sizes = [10,30,50, 100],
      calculated = sizes.map(function(size){return width*size/100}),
      node, 
      i, 
      nodeWidth,
      match,
      index;
  
     
    for (i=0;i<demo.childNodes.length;i++){
      node = demo.childNodes[i];
      node.classList.remove('size-1','size-2','size-3','size-4');
      
      nodeWidth = node.clientWidth;
      match = calculated.filter(function(grid){
        return grid >= nodeWidth;
      })[0];
      index = calculated.indexOf(match);
      
      
      node.classList.add( 'size-' + (index+1));
    }
}
```

```css
#demo{
  display:block;
  padding:0 0 0 1px;
  overflow:auto;
}

#demo .word{
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #999;
}

#demo .size-1{width:10%}
#demo .size-2{width:30%}
#demo .size-3{width:50%}
#demo .size-4{width:100%}
```

```html
<button onclick="wordsinblocks(this);">Design the sentence</button>
<p id="demo">Here is an amazing sentence well composed</p>
```

Comment: That is much better indeed, no more responsive problem now.

Comment: Hi. Any idea of how to apply it to class instead of div ? I tryed to change "getElementById" by "getElementsByClassName" but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Simtwo the `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection and not a single element. So you will need to iterate its elements (*the actual DOM nodes*) and run the script to those (*because the code works on a single node and its children*)

Comment: Wow ok I have no idea of how to do that. Let's go for research. Thank you for your fast answer

Answer (score 2):

Before you put your words back in html, wrap each word into a span and style the spans. This is just the part of how would you design the spans. Based on letter count you could add grid classes to them.

Please note that i didn't write the styles for the grid classes, therefore that won't be visible.

```js
function wordsinblocks() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var res = str.split(" ");

    for (var x in res) {
      var l = res[x].length;
      var className = "grid-1";

      switch(true) {
          case (l < 3):
             className = "grid-1";
          break;
          case (l > 2 && l < 5):
             className = "grid-2";
          break;
          // and so on until you get all cases you wish to cover
          default: // and finally longer words would have the widest column class
             className = "grid-4";
          break;
      }

      res[x] = '<span class="word-item ' + className + '">' + res[x] + '</span>';
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res.join(""); 
}
```

```css
 body{
    font-family:"helvetica";
    font-size: 40px;
    }
p span.word-item {border: 1px solid black; padding: 0 0.5em; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<button onclick="wordsinblocks();">Design the sentence</button>
<p id="demo">Here is an amazing sentence well composed</p>
```

Comment: This is exactly it. Thank you very much, now I have to search to make it responsive, but thats another matter. Thank you for the fast answer

Comment: @Simtwo keep in mind that going by character count means that it will only work correctly if you are using a fixed-width font. otherwise "*iiiii*" will always be much shorter than "*ooooo*"

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli : That's what I see now, thats a problem... Is it possible to see how it could be with the word width instead of character count ?

Comment: There's a lot of variance in character widths. [See this hilarious question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3949422/5743988).

Comment: Ok got it. So... have to make research about Pixels. Because some of my text break this grid.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? The result might not fully represent your picture but it does calculate the length of each word and apply a class accordingly:

```js
$("p span").each(function() {
  // get length of word characters
  var l = $(this).text().length; 
  // apply 10 percent class if equal or to less than 2 characters
  if (l <= 2) {
    $(this).addClass('p10'); }
  // apply 30 percent class if equal or to less than 5 characters
  else if (l <= 5) {
    $(this).addClass('p30'); }
  // otherwise, apply a 50 percent class
  else {
    $(this).addClass('p50')
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.p10 {
  width: 10%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.p30 {
  width: 30%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.p50 {
  width: 50%;
  background: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="p10">10 percent</span>
<span class="p30">30 percent</span>
<span class="p50">50 percent</span>

<p>
  <span>Here</span>
  <span>is</span>
  <span>an</span>
  <span>amazing</span>
  <span>sentence</span>
  <span>well</span>
  <span>composed</span>
</p>
```